# Is there a way to call a Javascript class method from ExternalInterface?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, externalinterface

I can call JS functions with `ExternalInterface.call('func_name',.args)`. OK

But what if I would like to call a js class instance method instead?

```
ExternalInterface.call('obj.method_name',.args) //this seems not to work
```

Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: Why don't you wrap the class return in a function?

Answer (score 2):

It was only a matter of scope. You must instantiated the swf object outside the js class. Then I can reference it in `ExternalInterface.call()`.

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){

    swf = new Swiff('../files/swf/italy.swf',{
        id:'italy',
        container:'italy-flash',
        width:280,
        height:323,
        params:{
            bgcolor:'#ffffff',
            wmode:'opaque',
            allowScriptAccess:'always'
        }
    });

    rm = new RelessersManager('regions');

});
```

Now from the swf I can call the `rm` methods. :) `(.call('rm.method_name',...params))`
Previously, I built the swf inside `rm`, so there was no way to reference `rm` from the swf.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a JavaScript-Method with ExternalInterface.
Be sure, you have included your JavaScript-Files or you have written your JavaScript-Function inside your index.template.html-file, this could looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function doSomtething() {
    alert("Something is done");
  }
</script>
```

If you want to call the function "doSomething()" you can do this with the following code:

```
ExternalInterface.call("doSomething");
```

If you want to send some parameter and your JavaScript Function is defined like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function doSomtething(param1, param2) {
    alert("Something is done");
  }
</script>
```

You can call it with this statement:

```
ExternalInterface.call("doSomething", param1, param2);
```

If this is not working, check your JavaScript-Functions inside your html-file.

You have posted the following statement:

```
ExternalInterface.call('obj.method_name',.args)
```

Are you sure you want to send ".args" instead of "args"?

I hope this will help you a little bit.

Comment: Mmm no my question was different. Anyway, I solved by myself.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missunderstood that - but fine that you have solved your problem.